# $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition for continuity of $x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, proof-verification

> Show that $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R,x\mapsto x^n$ with $n\in\Bbb N$ is continuous in $x_0=0$ using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-definition.

We assume that

$$\forall \varepsilon>0\;\exists\delta>0\;\forall x\in\Bbb R:|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon.$$

Trivially $x<\delta$ holds. On the right side we have $x^n<\varepsilon$. Does it suffice to say that the implication is true for all $\delta=\sqrt[n]{\varepsilon}$ as $x^n < \delta^n <\varepsilon$?

Comment: Sorry, didn't take the time to read your proposed solution, which is correct.

Comment: Except for the logic of your answer which is all over the place. You can't *assume* the statement defining continuity. This is what you need to *verify*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary. Then $|f(x) - f(0)| = |x|^n < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-0| = |x| < \delta:= \epsilon^{1/n}$.

Comment: Dear @Frank: The fact that all the positive real numbers has an $n$-th root is something that need to be proven, and is very common use the continuity of $x^n$ to prove it, which is in this case a little circular (of course, this can be prove it using just the lub property of the reals).

Comment: @JoseAntonio Yes, good point. However, I allowed myself to assume this, in the absence of further requirements for the solution in the question. And I'd bet by bottom dollar that whoever set this question was anticipating precisely this answer, and not a more sophisticated answer taking into account an overview of the elaborate construction of all basic analytical properties of the reals.

Comment: I see the point. This can  also be solved without assuming the $n$-th root. For example setting $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{\varepsilon+1}$, clearly $\delta<1$ and so, by induction on $n$, $\delta^n\le \delta<\varepsilon$. Sorry for being annoying =). Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you've already proven the existence of the $n$-th root for the positive real numbers, is a non-trivial result. So in ordered to avoid this fact which commonly is prove it using the continuity of $x^n$. We can use the following argument:

$\delta =\frac{\varepsilon}{1+\varepsilon} $ and then for $|x-0|<\delta$ we have $|x^n|< \delta ^n$. Since $\delta<1$, then $\delta^n\le \delta$, which follows by induction on $n$. Then $|x^n|<\delta^n\le \delta$. Plainly $\delta< \varepsilon$. Thus $|x^n-0|<\varepsilon$.